# Selecting ID's dynamically in js/ JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html form. Whenever i click add button another copy of it appends. Whenever i click add button, id of my elements increases such as username_0, username_1, username_2... There are 2 radio buttons on my form that whenever i choose second radio button, a hidden textarea appears. Problem is i'm having problem with choosing my dynamic id's of radio buttons. I made a function but its only working for first element since i can't get dynamic id's

```
    <label for="evetKontrol_0">Evet</label>
    <input type="radio" id="evetKontrol_0" name="uygun_0" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" value="uygun" checked>
    <label for="hayirKontrol_0">Hayır</label>
    <input type="radio" id="hayirKontrol_0" name="uygun_0" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" value="uygunDegil">
    <div id="ifNo_0" style="visibility:hidden">
        <strong>Uygun Olmama Sebebi:</strong> <input type="textarea" id="hayirSebep_0" name="hayirSebep" style="height: 75px"><br>
    </div>
```

```
    function yesnoCheck() {
      if (document.getElementById('evetKontrol_0').checked) {
          document.getElementById('ifNo_0').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
      else document.getElementById('ifNo_0').style.visibility = 'visible';


    }
```

I need to be able to get my `evetKontrol_#somenumber` for my function for every copy of my form.

[JSfiddle/ all of my code](https://jsfiddle.net/0ef6z9pb)

I tried to use `jQuery( "[attribute*='value']" )` but i couldn't manage to work it out.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you're using the `id` selector. You're better off with the `class` selector. For example, tag every `evetKontrol_0` type radio item with `class="evetKontrol"`. Then, use <div class="ifNo"> instead/in addition to id. Now, loop through the found "evetKontrol" classes to find the nearest `div.ifNo` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/sonvakq2/21/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

  function addElement(tObj) {
    var counter = $("[id^='ogrenci']", tObj).length;
    var html = '<div class="col-auto" id="ogrenci_' + counter + '"><label for="ad">Ad</label><input type="text" name="ad[]" class="form-control" id="ad_' + counter + '" placeholder="Öğrencinin Adı"/><label for="soyad">Soyad</label><input type="text" name="soyad[]" class="form-control" id="soyad_' + counter + '" placeholder="Öğrencinin Soyadı"/><label for="no">No</label><input type="text" name="numara[]" class="form-control" id="no_' + counter + '" placeholder="Öğrencinin Numarası"><label for="course">Bölümü</label><input type="text" name="bolum[]" class="form-control" id="course_' + counter + '" placeholder="Öğrencinin Bölümü"><label for="alKredi">Almak İstediği Kredi</label><input type="text" name="alKredi[]" class="form-control" id="alKredi_' + counter + '" placeholder="Almak İstediği Kredi"><label for="verKredi">Alabileceği Kredi</label><input type="text" name="verKredi[]" class="form-control" id="verKredi_' + counter + '" placeholder="Alabileceği Kredi"><label for=""><strong>Uygun mu?</strong> </label><br><label for="evetKontrol_' + counter + '">Evet</label><input type="radio" id="evetKontrol_' + counter + '" name="uygun_' + counter + '" value="uygun" checked><label for="hayirKontrol_' + counter + '">Hayır</label><input type="radio" id="hayirKontrol_' + counter + '" name="uygun_' + counter + '" value="uygunDegil"><div id="ifNo_' + counter + '" style="visibility:hidden"><strong>Uygun Olmama Sebebi:</strong> <input type="textarea" id="hayirSebep_' + counter + '" name="hayirSebep" style="height: 75px"><br></div><div class="input-group-addon"><a href="#" id="remove_' + counter + '" class="btn btn-danger remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</a></div></div>';
    tObj.append(html);
  }

  function showHidden() {
    $("[id^='evetKontrol']").each(function(i, el) {
      var rel = $("#ifNo_" + i);
      if ($(el).is(":checked")) {
        rel.show();
      } else {
        rel.hide();
      }
    });
  }

  //add more fields group
  $("#add").click(function() {
    addElement($("#container"));
  });

  //remove fields group
  $('#container').on('click', "a[id^='remove']", function() {
    $(this).parents('div.col-auto').remove();
  });

  $("#container").on("click", "input[type='radio']", showHidden);
});
```

Your fiddle wasn't configured properly, so I addressed that first. I moved a lot of the repeatable items into Functions. Switched it all the jQuery and removed any of the local javascript calls.

You can see examples of how to use the Attribute selector in a relative manner to select items you want.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: I understand the logic behind the code  and it seems perfectly fine but it doesn't seem to work when i check radiobuttons, textarea wouldn't show up. @Twisty

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use IDs for this. Just capture the onclick event and pass a boolean to determine if the hidden input should be shown. If you have multiple inputs to show and hide separately, you could pass the ID of the input along with the boolean.

```js
function yesnoCheck(show) {
  var ta = document.getElementById('hiddenTA');
  if (show) {
    ta.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    ta.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="user1_0">User 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="users" id="user1_0" onclick="yesnoCheck(false)" checked />
<label for="user2_0">User 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="users" id="user2_0" onclick="yesnoCheck(true)" />

<input style="visibility:hidden" id="hiddenTA" />
```

Comment: I don't have multiple inputs to show and hide. I have one input to show and hide i'll have lots of them. I need them to be unique, thats why i was using IDs. This works for my first form only.  I will be storing every unique data from form in SQL database.

Comment: @acaiberry, I am slightly confused. You have a single text input, but multiple radio inputs.  You can still use IDs just like you were, but you just need to pass a boolean to say whether or not the input should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the `evetKontrol_#somenumber`, pass that number in the `onclick` function.

In your JSfiddle, this would mean concatenating the `counter` variable into the function parameters like

```
... onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck(' + counter + ');" ...
```

Then update the function to use that value:

```
function yesnoCheck(counter) {
  if (document.getElementById('evetKontrol_' + counter).checked) {
    document.getElementById('ifNo_' + counter).style.visibility = 'hidden';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('ifNo_' + counter).style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
```